# Change multiple object attributes in a single line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering, when you create an object you can often set multiple attributes in a single line eg:

```
 @object = Model.new(:attr1=>"asdf", :attr2 => 13, :attr3 => "asdfasdfasfd")
```

What if I want to use find_or_create_by first, and then change other attributes later? Typically, I would have to use multiple lines eg:
     @object = Model.find_or_create_by_attr1_and_attr2("asdf", 13)
     @object.attr3 = "asdfasdf"
     @object.attr4 = "asdf"

Is there some way to set attributes using a hash similar to how the Model.new method accepts key-value pairs? I'm interested in this because I would be able to set multiple attributes on a single line like:

```
 @object = Model.find_or_create_by_attr1_and_attr2("asdf", 13)
 @object.some_method(:attr3 => "asdfasdf", :attr4 => "asdfasdf")
```

If anyone has any ideas, that would be great!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You want to use [`assign_attributes`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes) or [`update`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update) (which is an alias for the deprecated `update_attributes`):

```
@object.assign_attributes(:attr3 => "asdfasdf", :attr4 => "asdfasdf")

@object.update(attr3: "asdfasdf", attr4: "asdfasdf")
```

If you choose to `update` instead, the object will be saved immediately (pending any validations, of course).

Comment: Oh, hey, @jay, by the way! :^)

Comment: hey this doesn't work, i get an undefined method error.. and, hey? have you answered one of my questions before?

Comment: Yeah..something about the `:serialize` class method last night. What version of rails are you using?

Comment: rails 3.0.9 - oh yeah! thanks for that answer, serialize is awesome!

Comment: You bet! 3.0.9 should still be fine..Stupid question, but you aren't trying to assign to `@object` before you've instantiated it, are you?

Comment: umm I don't think so.. it's undefined method for #<Draft:0x0000010634aa88> (I do a find_or_create_by and then assign_attributes on the next line). I thought maybe it was because I didn't put attr_accessible in my model but I do have that.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I've seen that before. `attr_accessible` shouldn't *technically* be required, but as @veraticus noted it's a Really Good Idea...doubt that's the issue. Do all the attributes you're trying to assign exist in the model/table?

Comment: Yeah they do. I don't know why it's not working, but this is the right answer. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 4):

The methods you're looking for are called `assign_attributes` or `update_attributes`.

```
@object.assign_attributes(:attr3 => "asdfasdf", :attr4 => "asdfasf") # @object now has attr3 and attr4 set.
@object.update_attributes(:attr3 => "asdfasdf", :attr4 => "asdfasf") # @object now has attr3 and attr4 set and committed to the database.
```

There are some security concerns with using these methods in Rails applications. If you're going to use either one, especially in a controller, be sure to check out the documentation on [attr_accessible](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible) so that malicious users can't pass arbitrary information into model fields you would prefer didn't become mass assignable.

Comment: hey, this doesn't work.. I get an undefined method error, both in rails console and in the controller. It looks legit though..